# $f$ is analytic and $|f|$ is constant implies $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on a very simple proposition in Bak, specifically how the second to last line was obtained:
$$ \tag 1 (u^2 + v^2)u_x = 0 $$

The full proof is very short, and given below.

[image]

It appears the 2 equations immediately above $(1)$ is at that's needed for the result. But to get the squared terms $u^2$ and $v^2$, I don't see how you avoid square terms in the partials.

So to be specific, I want to see a justification of how the 2 equations (or earlier arguments) justify $(1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u(uu_x-vu_y)+v(vu_x+uu_y)\equiv0.$